# Generating UUID in react using crypto api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uuid

According to MDM (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID)
Most modern Browsers support the javascript native crypto api, which supports the former
node-js crypto standard.

According to this article in plain js I may create an uuid via

```
crypto.randomUUID()
```

Is there any way to use this interface in react? Since crypto seems to refere to a completely different object in react.

ps. I am aware of the existence of the UUID package, and know that its a common way to generate UUIDs I am just curious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [crypto.createPrivateKey is not a function in a next.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74754833/crypto-createprivatekey-is-not-a-function-in-a-next-js-app)

Comment: I don't think so, I do not use next js and therefore no node rendering. Further, my question was answered about a year ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are right, the crypto package in React is a different one. To use the one from NodeJs you can call:

> window.crypto

I put it in the if to make sure, it is only rendered in the browser.

```
if (window !== undefined) {
    console.log('randomUUID', window.crypto.randomUUID());
}
```

or

```
import crypto from 'crypto';

console.log('crypto.randomUUID()', crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex'));
```

Comment: Trying to test the `window !== undefined` results in a reference error when the `window` variable is not defined.  The first example should instead be checking `typeof window === "undefined"`

Answer (score 8):

**(Modern solution in 2023)**

1. Next.js pre-renders your React page component on the server (represented as the `NextPage` type in TypeScript), so you need to add `import crypto from 'crypto'; crypto.randomUUID()` to generate a unique id on the server.
2. After the HTML page is returned to the browser as a result of pre-rendering, you need to use `window.crypto.randomUUID()` because `crypto.randomUUID()` is from the Node.js package in the server environment, not in the browser. U can add the following check to your code:

```js
// The following Node.js package is imported on the server-side 
// and not available in the browser
import nodeCrypto from 'crypto';

// Use the web browser Crypto API if you're on the client, 
// otherwise use the Node.js Crypto API on the server
typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.crypto.randomUUID() : nodeCrypto.randomUUID()
```

See [Safely Accessing Web APIs](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-create-react-app#safely-accessing-web-apis) on the Next.js doc to learn more.

Comment: The question is actually not about next.js, it is meant to find a general solution that works for clientside rendered code.

Answer (score -1):

`window.crypto.randomUUID()` is fine. But please note that `crypto.randomUUID()` is only available in secure context (HTTPS). It will lead to the `TypeError: window.crypto.randomUUID is not a function` when you are on HTTP sites.

So it should be something like:

```js
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window.crypto.randomUUID === "function") {
    console.log('randomUUID', window.crypto.randomUUID());
}
```