# Using Web Crypto API in NextJS, but getting error 'crypto is not defined'

Tags: javascript, next.js, webapi

Can I use web crypto api in NextJS?

I tried to use

```
crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data)
```

but getting an error

```
ReferenceError: crypto is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating UUID in react using crypto api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127816/generating-uuid-in-react-using-crypto-api)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

before use `crypto` module, just import `import crypto from "crypto"`

here are example for [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)

Comment: Don't do this people. Bad link too

Comment: Or const crypto = require('crypto'); if you get "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: @LuisMartinez Why? Can you argument that? I don't quite understand why i shouldn't use this in NextJS

Comment: Didn't have to import anything with Next.js; just works out of the box FYI.

Comment: Node crypto module is different to Web crypto. I got errors in other parts of Next for using Node crypto module. `crypto.subtle.digest` does not exit in Node. Thought the point of it is that Next are moving to "edge functions" which don't have Node modules.

Answer (score 11):

For me, it worked when I used `import * as`

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it with

`const crypto = require('crypto');`

or also by using

`import crypto from "crypto"`